# Navigation menu swap item positions

Tags: css, moodle, nav

[I want to move Other Languages in the positions of My modules and My modules to Other Languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IuEi.png)

This is a moodle platform and i am trying to find some additional css or html to put inside

i try testing with nth-child but did not find a solution

```css
.navbar .nav>ul {
  display: flex-start;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
  order: 2; /* Swap positions with child 2 */
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1; /* Swap positions with child 1 */
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, what did you tried, try to do a a minimal reproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Remember to never edit the theme code itself but to write a child theme. Touching core code (it includes themes like boost or classic), is a big no no as it would disappear each time you update.

An easier solution solution to your problem would be to extend the menu class.

Since you didn't specify which theme you bases your on, i'll take the exemple of the boost one. You can extend the boostnavbar class then you can juste use $this->items to manage the order

Comment: Can you create a snippet where the problem you speak of reproduces and another one with your best attempt to solve it?

Comment: I can't find "my modules" or "other languages" in the Moodle code. Which version of Moodle are you using? Also, go to site admin > development > debugging > tick the box for "Show origin of languages strings" then add `?strings=1` or `&strings=1` to the url to display the origin of the text